# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Core"

Tags: xcode, firebase, cocoapods

Here is my Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'Unity-iPhone' do
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '7.3.1'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
end
```

It works well when I run 'pod install'

output:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Firebase (4.13.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (4.2.0)
Using FirebaseCore (4.0.20)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (2.0.10)
Using Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.3.1)
Using GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.4)
Using nanopb (0.3.901)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the Podfile and 7 total pods installed.
```

Perfect, everything is fine,But if I add a specific version with FirebaseCore,like below code:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core','4.0.20'
```

and 'pod install' again

output:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Core":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Core (= 4.0.20)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/Core (= 4.0.20)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.
```

Actually,FirebaseCore with 4.0.20 is exist,So how should I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it right now, just change Firebase/Core to FirebaseCore
(I was checked FirebaseCore.podspec file in GitHub.)

Comment: Worked well, but I had to change all my firebase dependencies in the podfile.

Answer (score 1):

The podspec versioning for `Firebase` and `FirebaseCore` are separate, so you shouldn't use them interchangeably. The `Firebase` pod is a parent for the subspecs `Firebase/Core`, `Firebase/Analytics`, etc., but `FirebaseCore` is not using the same versioning because `FirebaseCore` is not a subspec of `Firebase`, whereas `Firebase/Core` is.

For reference, the `Firebase` podspec is here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/980d013a857e7ef973531f1cf85ddb5b8a56d1b0/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.10.0/Firebase.podspec.json

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands in your **project/ios** folder in the order:

```
pod update Firebase/Core 
pod install --repo-update
```